# How can I use jq to find all paths in a JSON object under which a value matches a given criteria?

Tags: json, jq

Is there a way I could use jq to find all paths that hold a value that matches a given criteria?

For example, given the following JSON, I'd like to return all paths where the value of "age" is >35, regardless of the depth of the structure containing that field:

```
{  
  "springfield":{  
    "marge":{  
      "age":30
    },
    "homer":{  
      "age":40,
      "job":"xyz"
    }
  },
  "shelbyville":{  
    "zone1":{  
      "john":{  
        "age":10
      }
    },
    "zone2":{  
      "mark":{  
        "age":50
      }
    }
  },
  "homeless1":{  
    "age":25
  },
  "homeless2":{  
    "age":60
  }
}
```

So the execution would yield something like:

```
[
  ["springfield", "homer"],
  ["shelbyville", "zone2", "mark"],
  ["homeless2"]
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[paths(.age?>35)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following has been tested with jq 1.4 and jq 1.5:

```
$ jq -M -c '(paths | select(.[length-1] =="age")) as $path
    | if (getpath($path) > 35) then $path else empty end' ages.json
["springfield","homer","age"]
["shelbyville","zone2","mark","age"]
["homeless2","age"]
```

The following requires jq 1.5:

```
$ jq -c --stream 'select(length == 2 and .[0][-1] == "age" 
    and .[1] > 35)' ages.json
[["springfield","homer","age"],40]
[["shelbyville","zone2","mark","age"],50]
[["homeless2","age"],60]
```

These can both easily be adapted to produce similar output.